# Does JPA and Hibernate automatically update database without transaction begin and commit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, transactions

In JPA, if I try to update a managed object using  setter and getter method without using transaction begin and commit, does JPA automatically update the database ( not immediately but later) considering `FlushType` is in `AUTO`.

Comment: You need a transaction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984968/jpa-without-transaction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In JPA, the entity state transitions are not automatically synchronized with the database. If the entity is attached to the persistence context, then at [flush-time](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/), the [automatic dirty checking mechanism](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/) translates object state changes into DML statements.

But that requires the entity to be managed by the persistence context, as otherwise, the dirty checking mechanism will not trigger.

Although the JPA specification requires only [entity state transitions](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/) to be wrapped in a logical transaction:

- [`persist`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/)
- [`merge`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/)
- [`remove`](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)

[You should ALWAYS use transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327274/do-you-need-transaction-for-reading-data/26327536#26327536), even when only reading data.

If you don't explicitly use transactions when reading data, then you fall back to auto-commit mode, putting additional pressure on the connection pooling mechanism, and ending up with one database transaction per query.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation I use (DataNucleus JPA) does allow this (like an auto-commit mode). If that mode is not enabled then it falls back to what standard JPA does which is to hold on to those changes until the next transaction.