# How to avoid caching of entites in Spring Repository during a Transaction for tests

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a Test like this:

```
@Transactional
@Test
public void addRemoveTest() {
    MyEntitiy entity = new MyEntitiy ();

    entity = textureRepository.saveAndFlush(entity );
    TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
    TestTransaction.end();
    TestTransaction.start();
    final MyEntitiy loadedTexture = myEntityRepository.findOne(entity .getId());
}
```

This works perfectly fine. But when I remove the Committing code for the transaction, the repository will not call the database when calling `findOne()`. Can I somehow force it to make the database call for my tests?

I prefer my test to not commit any transaction.

I'm not able to get the `Session` to clear the cache. And I'm not even sure if clearing the session would help.

Comment: One worarround is to use `findAll()` since I just want my UserType to be executed that works for me :)

Comment: `.findOne` should change to `.getOne`, they are different. Beside that why you need to force it to make the database call. It's not necessary.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The only way I know is to call `entityManager.clear()` before calling the finder. I think you can autowire the `EntityManager` into your test:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Your test would then look like this:

```
@Transactional
@Test
public void addRemoveTest() {
    MyEntitiy entity = new MyEntitiy ();

    entity = textureRepository.saveAndFlush(entity );
    entityManager.clear();
    final MyEntitiy loadedTexture = myEntityRepository.findOne(entity .getId());
}
```

Comment: I wrote an entire new question, and at the last second I saw this... Thank you!

Comment: This works too when the Entity has a attribute that is not writeable or updateable and has been inserted and you need to recover it value.