# Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class while running tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Recently upgrading my application from a very older versions. While running Tomcat getting the below error.
I'm using the below hibernate dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.11.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.11.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I'm using MySQL 8

Error while running Tomcat 9:

```
May 28, 2023 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.demoweb.web.util.demoWebContextListener]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:287)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.FullTextSessionImpl.doUnwrap(FullTextSessionImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.FullTextSessionImpl.<init>(FullTextSessionImpl.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.ImplementationFactory.createFullTextSession(ImplementationFactory.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.search.Search.getFullTextSession(Search.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(Search.java:49)
    at com.demoweb.web.util.demoWebContextListener.contextInitialized(demoWebContextListener.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4946)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1910)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)

May 28, 2023 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
May 28, 2023 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/abc] startup failed due to previous errors
May 28, 2023 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
May 28, 2023 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
WARNING: The web application [abc] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
May 28, 2023 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [abc] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
May 28, 2023 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [abc] appears to have started a thread named [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:91)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
May 28, 2023 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [abc] appears to have started a thread named [Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index com.demoweb.backend.model.MomentBO] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:338)
 org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor.parkCurrentThread(SyncWorkProcessor.java:179)
 org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor.access$300(SyncWorkProcessor.java:37)
 org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:149)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
May 28, 2023 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [abc] appears to have started a thread named [Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index com.demoweb.backend.model.LessonBO] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:338)
 org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor.parkCurrentThread(SyncWorkProcessor.java:179)
 org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor.access$300(SyncWorkProcessor.java:37)
 org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:149)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
May 28, 2023 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive [D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.74\webapps\abc.war] has finished in [34,067] ms
May 28, 2023 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

Adding the `demoWebContextListener.java` from line 68-74:
`DemoConstants.ENTITY_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME` value is `"entityManager"`

```
entityManager = (EntityManager) applicationContext.getBean(DemoConstants.ENTITY_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME);
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
try {
    fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer(LessonBO.class).startAndWait();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`bean` definition in `applicationContext.xml` file:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="com.demo.backend.util.DemoLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="demoDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="demo" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="${demo.database.generateddl}" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${demo.database.platform}" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: i tried to add this line "entityManager=entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();" but this gives null pointer exception(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522691/java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-transactional-entitymanager-available)

Comment: making method transactional resolved the issue